# OpenID and Oauth2 server on Java

Tags: java, openid, oauth-2.0

Where can I get a tutorial or instruction how to implement my own OpenID and Oauth2 servers for authorizing my microservice? I use java app and microservice I want to put authorization to. Where can I get an example of this auth server and may be there existing ones in the internet?

Comment: Check http://www.keycloak.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check http://www.keycloak.org  This is an open source authentication server by Red Hat.  Tons of documentation, start from here:http://www.keycloak.org/documentation.html

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a glance at [MitreID-Connect project](https://github.com/mitreid-connect/OpenID-Connect-Java-Spring-Server) over at github. The project claims to be the reference implementation of OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 and the guy behind it is active in the specification working groups.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some at "**[Libraries, Products, and Tools](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)**" page in the [website of OpenID Connect](http://openid.net/connect/). Of course, there are many other implementations which are not listed there and *[java-oauth-server](https://github.com/authlete/java-oauth-server)* is one of such examples.

If you are going to implement your own OAuth 2.0 & OpenID Connect server, you will be able to find some insights in this article *"[Full-Scratch Implementor of OAuth and OpenID Connect Talks About Findings](https://medium.com/@darutk/full-scratch-implementor-of-oauth-and-openid-connect-talks-about-findings-55015f36d1c3)"*. Especially, be careful when you write code for Redirect URI. Otherwise, security risks of your server would be increased.